# ConcurrentModificationError when adding item to a list

Tags: flutter, list, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

First, here's my code :

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
List favMangasListTitle = [];
List detailledMangaList = [];
String title = '1';
String read_chapter = '1';
Future<List> getFavMangas() async {
  var value = await firestore.collection("users/${user.uid}/fav_mangas").get();
  final favMangasGetter = value.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  favMangasListTitle.clear();
  detailledMangaList.clear();
  for (var i in favMangasGetter) {
    title = i['title'];
    read_chapter = i['read_chapter'];
    favMangasListTitle.add(title);
  }

  for (var i in favMangasListTitle) {
    final mangas = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('mangas')
        .where('title', isEqualTo: i)
        .get();

    final receivedMangaDetailled =
        mangas.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    detailledMangaList.addAll(receivedMangaDetailled);
  }
  print(detailledMangaList);
  return detailledMangaList;
}
```

I have a button where I add some mangas to my favorites :
[image: Screenshot]

When I add one or most mangas, I have this error (line 17)

> ConcurrentModificationError (Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:7) of '_GrowableList'.)

It seems to be from my second for loop. But I can't resolve it for 5 days !
Sometimes it's work and sometimes not.

EDIT :

Here's my onPressed action :

```
Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      updateFavMangaList();
                      setState(() {});
                      Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MangathequePage()))
                          .then((value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // refresh state
                        });
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    label: Text('Suivant'),
                  )),
```

and how I add my datas :

```
  Future<void> updateFavMangaList() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('fav_mangas')
        .get();

    for (var i in favMangaList) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('fav_mangas')
          .add({'title': i, 'read_chapter': '0'});
    }
  }
```

Comment: On which line does the error happen

Comment: Line 17, when the second for loop begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an await before your updateFavMangaList method, since it returns a Future. This looks like an async problem

```
onPressed: () async {
   await updateFavMangaList();
```

Comment: async calls with await in a foor loop can be pretty nasty. I searched for "await in for loop" and this was one of the solutions I found :D

Comment: I removed the T type in my answer

Comment: Sorry but your answer seems to work, but now, it's doing the same thing as the begining...

Comment: Did you add any new features? Can you show me also the onPress logic

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay ! I've updated my post. I only added a feature where I filter my result. But even if I go back, the original prolem is still here

Comment: Hmm ... where do you call getFavMangas? And can you put an await before updateFavMangaList in your onPressed? Looks like an async problem

Comment: OK ! So, the problem seems to be from the onPressed logic. As you said, I had to add async/await before updateFavMangaList and It's working. I've restarted my emulator, disconnected and reconnected my app account, reloaded 4 times ! So now I'm sure it's working  ! Thanks you very much for your help, I hope I will don't have to come back :D !

Comment: My guess is you call the updateFavMangaList function which updates your list of mangas (which takes some time, since its async!), but you also call setState after it. And this triggers your build method, where you loop over your manga list to display it on the screen or something like that and this is a big nono. Going through a list and changing it in the process is dangerous